# Develop Sales Funnel UI using chartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

We have been asked to implement this sales funnel wireframe now using chartJS instead of highcharts. We worked on the implementation and do not know how to make changes to make it look like the wireframe provided.

What changes have to be made in order for :

- UI to match the wireframe ?
- How to disable hover entirely for the chart UI ?

[image: Wireframe]

This is what has been developed in UI :

[image]

The code writtten for the same is as follows :

```
import './App.css';
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
import { CategoryScale } from "chart.js";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Data } from "./Data";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
Chart.register(CategoryScale);
 
function App() {
  const [chartData] = useState({
    labels: Data.map((data) => data.year), 
    // labels:[1,2,3,4],
    datasets: [
   
      {
        label: "Users Gained ",
        data: Data.map((data) => data.userGain),
        // data:[80000],
        type:"bar",
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
          "#E9B598",
          "#11C6F3",
          "#50AF95",
          "#f3ba2f",
          "#2a71d0"
        ],
        borderColor: "white",
        borderWidth: {top:0,right:1,left:1},
        barPercentage: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      // {
      //   label: "Users left",
      //   data: [89000,100900,75000,71000,50000,],
      //   // order:1,  
      //   borderColor:"#ffffff" ,
      //   borderWidth:{top:0,right:1,left:1},
      //   backgroundColor: '#D5D8DA',
      //   type:"bar",
      //   barPercentage: 1,
      //   categoryPercentage: 1  ,
        
          
      // },
      {
        type:"line",
        showLine:true,
        data:[
          [2016,180000],
          [2020,90000],
        ],
        fill:true,
        backgroundColor:'#D5D8DA',
        // xAxes:{
        //   min:0
        // }
      },
      {
        type:"line",
    
        data:[
          [0,0],
          [2020,90000]
          
        ],
        fill:true,
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        // order:1,
      
      },
    ]
  });
 const chartOptions={
 
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Users Gained between 2016-2020"
    },
    
  },
 
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true,
    
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true,
    
    },
    // xAxes: [
    //   {
     
    //   },
    // ],
  },
  

}
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Bar data={chartData} options={chartOptions}>
     </Bar>
    </div>
  );
}
```